Ansible win_package to uninstall Google Chrome. Fails with rc=19
The issue I’m facing is that, in the specific case of Google Chrome, the step "name: Uninstall program with route" fails with an rc=19, however, the software is successfully uninstalled but the step still fails with that return code. I can’t figure out, nor find, why this happens. Does anyone know what this code means and can help me? Does anyone know why this is occurring?
The version of Ansible I’m using is a bit old, as is the version of Python:
ansible 2.9.27
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Oct 6 2023, 09:53:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
This is why I have to pass the path to win_package, as this points to an .exe, and the module fails if I don’t provide it.
Additionally, I’ve noticed it’s the same return code I get when I uninstall via PowerShell by executing:
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $exe -ArgumentList $params -Wait -PassThru $process.WaitForExit() 
$exitCode = $process.Exit

Here’s the playbook.
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    aplication_name: "Google Chrome"
  tasks:
    - name: Bloque de desinstalacion
      block:
        - name: obtain id and uninstall string by aplication name
          ansible.windows.win_powershell:
            script: |
              $package_info = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* , HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
              Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*{{aplication_name}}*" } | ForEach-Object { "$($_.PSChildName)\n$($_.UninstallString)" }
              
              Write-Output $package_info
          register: package_info

        - name: extract product_id y path
          set_fact:
            product_id: "{{ package_info.output[0].split('\\n')[0] }}"
            uninstall_path: "{{ package_info.output[0].split('\\n')[1].split('--')[0] | regex_replace('^\\s+|\\s+$', '') | regex_replace('^\"|\"$', '')  }}"

        - name: Uninstall program with route
          win_package:
            path: '{{uninstall_path}}'
            product_id: "{{product_id}}"
            arguments: '--uninstall --multi-install --system-level --force-uninstall'
            state: absent
          register: status
          ignore_errors: true
        
        - name: "debug uninstall_path"
          debug:
            msg: '{{ uninstall_path }}'
          when: primer_intento_desintalacion.failed

"I can't find any documentation or anything about it."

It may be error 0x10001.  See https://www.thewindowsclub.com/distributedcom-error-10001-unable-to-start-a-dcom-server
